# Why are LINQ extensions written in a very difficult to read way?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was checking some of the code that make up LINQ extensions in Reflector, and this is the kind of code I come across:

```
private bool MoveNext()
{
    bool flag;
    try
    {
        switch (this.<>1__state)
        {
            case 0:
                this.<>1__state = -1;
                this.<set>5__7b = new Set<TSource>(this.comparer);
                this.<>7__wrap7d = this.source.GetEnumerator();
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                goto Label_0092;

            case 2:
                this.<>1__state = 1;
                goto Label_0092;

            default:
                goto Label_00A5;
        }
    Label_0050:
        this.<element>5__7c = this.<>7__wrap7d.Current;
        if (this.<set>5__7b.Add(this.<element>5__7c))
        {
            this.<>2__current = this.<element>5__7c;
            this.<>1__state = 2;
            return true;
        }
    Label_0092:
        if (this.<>7__wrap7d.MoveNext())
        {
            goto Label_0050;
        }
        this.<>m__Finally7e();
    Label_00A5:
        flag = false;
    }
    fault
    {
        this.System.IDisposable.Dispose();
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Was there a reason for Microsoft to write it this way?

Also what does the <> syntax mean, in lines like:

```
switch (this.<>1__state)
```

I have never seen it written before a variable, only after.

Comment: FYI, I'll be doing a series in my blog on the design characteristics of iterator blocks in July.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I will look forward it for sure.

Answer (score 8):

The MSIL is still valid 2.x code and the <> names you're seeing are auto generated by the C# 3.x compilers.

For example:

```
public void AttachEvents()
{
    _ctl.Click += (sender,e) => MessageBox.Show( "Hello!" );
}
```

Translates to something like:

```
public void AttachEvents()
{
    _ctl.Click += new EventHandler( <>b_1 );
}

private void <>b_1( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    MessageBox.Show( "Hello!" );
}
```

I should also note that the reason you're seeing it like that in Reflector is that you don't have .NET 3.5 optimization turned on. Go to **View | Options** and change **Optimization** to .NET 3.5 and it will do a better job of translating the generated identifiers back to their lamda expressions.

Comment: I thought that those types of names were chosen to make sure that the names chosen do not conflict with anything you choose.

Answer (score 7):

You're seeing the internal guts of the [finite state machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine) that the C# compiler emits on your behalf when it handles [iterators](http://tinyurl.com/mso78t).

Jon Skeet has some great articles ([Iterator block implementation details](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) and  [Iterators, iterator blocks and data pipelines](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx)) on this subject. See also Chapter 6 of his [book](http://www.manning.com/skeet/).

There was [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131871/algorithm-for-implementing-c-yield-statement) an SO post on this subject.

And, finally, Microsoft Research has a nice [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/specsharp/iterators.pdf) on the subject.

Read until your heart is content.

Answer (score 2):

Identifiers starting with <> aren't valid C# identifiers, so I suspect they use them to mangle the names without fear of conflict, as no identifier in the C# code could be the same.

As to why it's hard to read, I suspect that it's more down to the fact it's easy to generate.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how other code would conflict with this?

Comment: Joan, other code WON'T conflict with this. That's the point. The compiler chooses intentionally illegal identifier names for its generated code so it can't possibly interfere with the user-written code it's compiling.

Comment: Not code, variable names.

You cannot have a variable name that contains <>, so nothing can conflict with it

Answer (score 2):

This is code that is automatically generated when you use [iterators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx).  The <> is used to ensure there are no collisions, and also to prevent you from accessing the compiler-generator classes directly in your code.

See the following for more information:

- [Using C# Yield for Readability and Performance](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/02/using-c-yield-for-readability-and-performance.html)
- [C# Iterators](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/06/07/liberty.html)

Comment: I didn't know <> characters were valid for variables.

Comment: They're not valid in C# but they are in IL. This means that the compiled code is perfectly legal, but you can't access the auto-generated types in your own code. It also means that the compiler can guarantee that the (illegal in C#) names of auto-generated types won't clash with the (legal in C#) names of any other types.

Answer (score 2):

These are types that have been auto-generated by the compiler from [iterator methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx).

The compiler will do exactly the same sort of thing to your own iterators. For example, write something like this and then take a look at the actual generated code in Reflector:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetRandom()
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    while (true)
    {
        yield return rng.Next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is state machine that is automatically generated from an iterator, such as the following:

```
static IEnumerable<Func<KeyValuePair<int, int>>> FunnyMethod() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var localVar = i;
        yield return () => new KeyValuePair(localVar, i);
    }
}
```

This method will return 10 for all of the values.

The compiler transforms these methods into state machines that store their state in the `<>1__state` field and call each part of the iterator for a different value of the field.

The `<>` part is part of the generated field name, and is chosen so as not to conflict with anything.

Answer (score 0):

You must understand what Reflector does.  It is not getting the source code back.  That's not what a developer at MS wrote. :)  It takes Intermediate Language (IL) and systematically converts it back to C# (or VB.NET).  In doing so, it must come up with an approach.  As you know there are many ways to skin a cat in code that will eventually lead to the same IL.  Reflector has to pick a way to move back wards from IL to a higher level language and use that way every time.

(Fixed per comment, thank you.)

Comment: These are not names picked by reflector. These are names generated by the compiler and used in the IL, as others have mentioned.